# Freemarker : Expression inside Expression

Tags: freemarker

Is there any way that i can use an expression inside expression in Freemarker?

Example:
XML FIle

```
<Document>
<Row>
<item_date>01/01/2015</item_date>
</Row>
<Row>
<item_date>02/01/2015</item_date>
</Row>
</Document>

<#list 0..1 as i>
${Document.Row[${i}].item_date}
</#list>
```

I want to print as below
    01/01/2015
    02/01/2015

Any idea?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
${Document.Row[i].item_date}
```

Note that if you are using an up-to-date version, you get this error message, which explains why:

> You can't use "${" here as you are already in
>   FreeMarker-expression-mode. Thus, instead of ${myExpression}, just
>   write myExpression. (${...} is only needed where otherwise static text
>   is expected, i.e, outside FreeMarker tags and ${...}-s.)